# Migrate Table to Sql XML field

Tags: xml, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, xsd

I'm very sorry for this long question! I don't know how to summarize it.
The case is very simple but I'm new to SQL XML.

I've a table and i want to migrate all records of it to another table with one xml column.

Here is my **Field table**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields] (
[Id]          BIGINT     IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[Duration]    INT        NOT NULL,
[Cost]        MONEY      NOT NULL,
[Consignee]   BIGINT     NOT NULL,
[Date]        DATETIME   NOT NULL,
[TariffId]    BIGINT     NOT NULL,
[InvoiceType] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
[IsPayed]     BIT        NOT NULL
);
```

and this one is my **TypedXML table**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TypedXml](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceItem] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[invoiceCollection])
```

Which have one **schema** collection like this:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION invoiceCollection AS 
'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://www.oliol.com" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="http://www.oliol.com">
 <xsd:element name="Invoice" type="InvoiceType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="InvoiceType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:long" />
      <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Duration" type="xsd:long" />
      <xsd:element name="Cost" type="xsd:decimal" />
      <xsd:element name="Consignee" type="xsd:long" />
      <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime" />
      <xsd:element name="TariffId" type="xsd:long" />
      <xsd:element name="InvoiceType" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="IsPayed" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>'
```

Now, I write this to **migrate**:

```
declare @i bigint
set @i=1
while(@i<=10000)
begin

insert into dbo.TypedXML(invoiceitem)
values(
(SELECT  *
FROM Fields
where id=1
FOR XML PATH('Invoice')))
set @i=@i+1
End
```

It can not insert, because it try to insert something like this:

**Insert Failed**

```
<Invoice>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Title>t1</Title>
  <Duration>726643700</Duration>
  <Cost>312118909727165.6133</Cost>
  <Consignee>3120910928797722624</Consignee>
  <Date>4543-07-16T01:40:29.623</Date>
  <TariffId>3120910928797722624</TariffId>
  <InvoiceType>it1</InvoiceType>
  <IsPayed>1</IsPayed>
</Invoice>
```

While I can insert into TypedXML like this:

**Insert Succeed**

```
INSERT typedxml VALUES('
<xml version=1>
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.oliol.com">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Title>t1</Title>
  <Duration>726643700</Duration>
  <Cost>312118909727165.6133</Cost>
  <Consignee>3120910928797722624</Consignee>
  <Date>4543-07-16T01:40:29.623</Date>
  <TariffId>3120910928797722624</TariffId>
  <InvoiceType>it1</InvoiceType>
  <IsPayed>1</IsPayed>
</Invoice>
')
```

I would like to know how can I change my migration query in order to append *xmlns="http://www.oliol.com"* to *Invoice* element?

**p.s:**
I've changed it like this:
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.oliol.com' as ns)
    SELECT  *
    FROM Fields
    where id=1
    FOR XML PATH('Invoice')
but it's not meet the schema because it produce:

```
<Invoice xmlns:ns="http://www.shaar.com">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Title>t1</Title>
  <Duration>726643700</Duration>
  <Cost>312118909727165.6133</Cost>
  <Consignee>3120910928797722624</Consignee>
  <Date>4543-07-16T01:40:29.623</Date>
  <TariffId>3120910928797722624</TariffId>
  <InvoiceType>it1</InvoiceType>
  <IsPayed>1</IsPayed>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your namespace using `default`:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.oliol.com')
```

Comment: Thank you Mikael! that was great! Is this kind of namespacing correct?

Comment: @Reza It is the correct way to generate the XML you want in SQL Server. I would not know if it is the optimal way to use a namespace in a schema like that. I have not so much experience with that.

Comment: That's exactly my question. What's the optimal way to use a namespace in a schema like that?

Comment: @Reza i think you should add that as a new question using only the XML and XML-SCHEMA tag.